# How to change the eclipse window colour based on the workspace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

If I'm working on live branch as well as development branch at almost same time, 
naturally the code in both the branches is similar, 
my two eclipse instances are open at the same time, 
I keep swapping between them and tend to commit mistake by adding code in the wrong workspace.

To distinguish between the two instances of eclipse if I could have different themes (colours), it could have been good fool proofing measure.

I would like different theme for the eclipse window than the code font or file background.
I use same eclipse (Helios) .exe for different workspaces.

Any simpler advice could also be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also add a name for each workspace.  Open `Preferences>General>Workspace` and enter a Workspace name.  It will be shown at the beginning of the title in the shell and the task bar.

That's how I differentiate my 4.2 and 3.8 workspaces, since I often need them both open to compare behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this I'm already doing and the only way to open two instances of same eclipse exe. Still this is bit inconvenient to identify the difference quickly.

Comment: The other thing you can do is to download and install some different themes.  Then use `Preferences>General>Appearance` in one workspace.  Search for themes in http://marketplace.eclipse.org

Answer (score 0):

You may right mouse click in the background of one of your files > Preferences > Text Editor and change background color.